# Weird return result on curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the page contents with cURL, but I get a weird result.. I should get a html..

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mypagehere.com"); //replaced the link with the original here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

but I get a result like:

```
‹Í]}sÛ8Îÿ;ù\í5q¶¶dç­‰»“¦/×½¾äiÒÝ»ét<²$ÛjdI'ÉI|Ý|÷ç”)ÇN²m7³Ý^-Q$H€‚ îð§çïÏþsòBŒŠqÔ]=¤úëßAü2ÉKDn<ìXAÜøxj  ?Ì:Ö›³–ð"7Ï;ÖÉ¤…žx“‡ÿ~RˆwÉiè}7³ÄÕ8Šóö ß±FE‘¶çòòÒ¸^ÐO’sÛKÆÎf³¹çúãÈ¢®×ï®®®ŽƒÂÞÈÍò èX“bÐØ³„CŸVWVûnˆQ*`ÃaÌû‰›ù¹ÃõQ9÷²0-ºh·ráf¢×á'ÞdÄ…=ŠQ@ù³é™;|çŽƒÚ:Á_ßøÔü\Gõ¢¾9úùnr85@^[C›F&~êPÛò_©î¡SŽˆ0-Â"
º/²,ÉÄâõ«wâÿÐ‘_ãÃ8QmóbŠêö¯ùû8šŠ¯˜<Üi[ÄIˆŸÂqšd…âqåC§lPQŸ‹,ˆ:ÍGAPXŠ˜^žÛé(}ŠßÎ ÉÆõ”§¶~ÄxMÖ¸E§µF,Xó;­­Ýæfk{»)É}ðŠêyàfÞ¨né²õsôRw¬¹ãô@÷HÏºW~žïdâ¿jºEžyËq<?¶“´Çáÿ‚hÊìñ%w6÷w¶šÍ-ûKnugÓAs#É,[+ŽM¦yá¡gcxáx˜3€wUüòßIMÕO£eïØ›ö8Œ«ëb¾±Ý›úè§½‹Îns§¹»?4š»›ÍÍfk³ŠPe¾Ý¨²Ø-KÓ4èXnšBp[;Yž?†°âñcÇúpz*AàL¼Á•šSiž“ÔŸŒs§á„±\Ù€+9³£Q—½ÁUá|q/\Iˆ¿˜ûCâZ¸©[¸Ñy/LGàðÞ8’<žÂœ†6‹‘›7@†ÇžP=”ø"<I|q–L¼ÑOâ˜ž‹÷ÿE""°\,ÆI†jý
ëLub[÷Ä$‹¥“8Èm¢fÀÌ1É¼8zè
```

The html should be echoed in retun, but it's not... what to do ?

Comment: What shows up when your browser makes the request?

Comment: It looks like a binary file - or wrong character encoding.

Comment: Okey I solved it.. just added:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: @BorisKremenovic You should post that as an answer, you can post an answer for your own question, that would help people having a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Okey I solved it.. just added:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
```